# i18n in Jinja + Django - Is it possible to put <span>. <b> and other tags inside {% trans %}

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm using coffin to interface with Jinja2 for Django templating.

I've run into a situation where I need to translate this piece of text which looks like this:

```
<a href= "#"> This is a test <b> text </b>.</a> The quick brown <span class="red"> fox </span>
```

so, i'm currently doing something like this to translate it

> < a href= "#">{% trans %}This is a test{% endtrans %} < b> {% trans %}text{%
>   endtrans %} < /b>. < /a> {% trans %}The quick brown{% endtrans %} < span
>   class="red"> {% trans %}fox{% endtrans %} < /span>

I can tell there must be an easier way to translate text which have html tags within them. What is the best way to proceed?

is this a valid way to do it?

```
{% trans %}<a href= "#">This is a test <b> text </b>. </a> The quick brown <span class="red"> fox </span>{% endtrans %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If only nested `trans` tags were supported...

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML tags inside your .po file. This way, your translators will have the full context of your strings and they can adjust the tags to match the intended result.

Answer (score -1):

While it is valid, it puts the burden of keeping valid HTML syntax on translators (not to mention being more volatile), so you should rather avoid doing this. AFAIR, you can do `<a href="">{{ _('This is a test') }} <b>{{ _('text') }}</b> ...` in Jinja, if you want a syntax with less tag noise.

Comment: A problem I see that might arise if that is done: the po file will have separate entries for 'this is a test' and for 'text'. They will be translated as disjoint pieces of text and concatenated in the view. This type of translation will not always be accurate for long and complex sentences. Breaking up and Re-constitution the translation will not be accurate. I hope that made sense.

Comment: +1, in some languages, 'text' will have to be BEFORE 'This is a test', so splitting a sentence in two msgid is a wrong way.